# Django + React Native. How to input data into Django from react native?

Tags: django, react-native

This is my first time working with react native and django. I am having trouble connecting them.

This is what I have currently. I am unsure of what to write in my json_uploadfunc function so that it would input the value, header, description, priority, duration, due, owner into django.

Where can I get more information and what should I write into json_uploadfunc?

```
export default class TaskClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {

            header: 'TestClassTask',
            description: '',
            priority: null,
            duration: null,
            due: null,
            owner: 'URL'

        }
    };

    json_funtion = () => {
        fetch('https://google.com')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var json_array = data[0];           //get the first obj from django
            var id = json_array.id.toString();  //get the id 
            var url = json_array.url;           //get url
            var header = json_array.header;     //get header
            var priority = json_array.priority.toString();  //get priority                 
            var duration = json_array.duration.toString();  //get duration
            var due = json_array.due.toString();            //get duedate
            var owner = json_array.owner;                   //get owner
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    json_uploadfun = () => {
        URLpath = https://url


    }
}
```

Comment: Pro tip -- you should really obscure (hide) the urls for your environment from posts. People are generally nice, but someone could start messing with your API now. Kinda like how you wouldn't post a picture of your credit card...

Comment: You need to send the data via Ajax and have corresponding Django views and forms to validate the data and send confirmation/errors back